# Dynamic no. of HTML images from JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html

I use jquery to read a file (output.txt). 
It contains below, and I split it into an array.

> name1.jpg,name2.jpg,name3.jpg,name4.jpg

I can output the length of the array and output images from the array, but I struggle to make the output dynamic.

Scenarios I would like to achieve:

- If fileReadingLength = 10, display 10 images (img1,img2,..,img10).
- If fileReadingLength = 1, display 1 image (img1).

What would the best approach for this be?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         var fileReading = new Array();
            $.get('output.txt', function(data){
                     fileReading = data.split(',');
            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#img1").attr({ "src": fileReading[0] });
               $("#img2").attr({ "src": fileReading[1] });
               $("fileReadingLength").text(fileReading.length);
            });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      Number of images: <fileReadingLength></fileReadingLength> <br>
      <!-- SHOULD BE CHANGED TO DYNAMIC OUTPUT -->
      <img id="img1" src="img1.jpg">
      <img id="img2" src="img2.jpg">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take the container (`body` here) and use `append` https://api.jquery.com/append/ in a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Append** the number according to the **length** of the fileReadingLength.Hope you will understand it.

`for (i = 1; i <= fileReadingLength; i++) {
      $('body').append('<img id="img"'+i+' src="img1.jpg">')
    }`

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. I added so it makes the src dynamic. 

$('body').append('<br><img id="img"'+i+' src="'+fileReading[i]+'">')

Answer (score 0):

my idea, i will use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for your array and `.append` it.

```js
//demo array img data
function randomImg(){
  let randomN = function(min, max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  }
  let res = [];
  let tot = randomN(1,10);
  for(let i = 1;i <= tot; i++){
    res.push(`img${i}`);
  }
  return res;
}

function randomMe(){
  var fileReading = new Array();
  // demo
  fileReading = randomImg();
  $("fileReadingLength").text(fileReading.length);
  $('#img-box-demo').html('');
  let c = 1;
  fileReading.map(function(i){
    $('#img-box-demo')
      .append(`
        <img 
          id="img-${c}" 
          src="../${i}?t=${Date.now()}" 
          title="${i}" />
       `);
    c++;
  });
}

$('#btn-ran-img').on('click', randomMe);
randomMe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <body>
    <button id="btn-ran-img">Random img</button><br/>
    Number of images: <fileReadingLength></fileReadingLength> <br>
    <!-- SHOULD BE CHANGED TO DYNAMIC OUTPUT -->
    <div id="img-box-demo"></div>
 </body>
```